# Exchanging iframe tab with Facebook wall

Tags: facebook, iframe

Good Day,

Is there any way one can have the Facebook Iframe tab as the default landing page on Facebook, after a user liked the page.

That means when ever a user who "liked" the page visit the facebook page again, he will see the tab first and not the wall as a default.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your page, go to `Edit Page`, go to `Manage Permissions`, there you will see `Default Landing Tab`...

[image]

Then parse `signed_request` and redirect user if needed...

Comment: Thank you, I have done that already. What is "parse" and where should I add then "signed_request"? Sorry I am not a programmer, but getting there :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to set the default landing tab for users who already like your page - only for users who don't already like the page